# angular state change after ng-file-upload success without any error or any reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to the server , I do that successfully but after success, angular or browser or I don't know how just redirect me back to my initial state in angular js

the success callback hit and I have no error

**ng-fileupload version 3.2.5**.

here is my function in the controller :

```
 $scope.uploadIssueAttachment = function (files, issue) {
      if (files && files.length) {
          for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              $upload.upload({
                  url: '/Handlers/UploadHandler.ashx?des=HelpDesk'
                  , method: 'POST'
                  , file: file
              , }).progress(function (evt) {}).then(function (data) {
                  var _fileName = data.headers('fileName');
                  var _originalFileName = data.headers('orgName');
                  var _type = data.headers('format');
                  $scope.newIssueAttachments.push({
                      fileName: _originalFileName
                      , temporaryName: _fileName
                      , fileType: _type
                  });
              }).catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
              });
          }
      }
  };
```

and here is my html markup

```
 <span ng-file-select ng-file-change="uploadIssueAttachment($files,newIssue)" class="file-input btn  btn-sm btn-file" >
```

the function hit and I upload a file, browser response with 200 status

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3080/Handlers/UploadHandler.ashx?des=HelpDesk
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:3080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 17 Jul 2017 10:33:56 GMT
fileName:ea8c8799-0f48-49f4-a33c-dca0726af929.png
format:image/png
name:ea8c8799-0f48-49f4-a33c-dca0726af929.png
orgname:avator.png
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcU291cmNlXFdvcmtzcGFjZXNcUE1PLkFDQVxEZXZcQk1TXFJheWthbS5Ccm9rZXJzLldlYi5NVkNcSGFuZGxlcnNcVXBsb2FkSGFuZGxlci5hc2h4?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16544
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarylgAXmkMLtLGhRRU4
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=ska22gomunzfvxqv1wwihbmh; .ASPXAUTH=A8E3E65AECDBB20189E01D261B3580E6997A7763615AD085A0E92F5F44B2D7DFA2C0E39BA47876EAE614EF06C56E692B71982D9035F84075C466E63632653E3E7CC03F042B850200EFBC2867E8A0F7EA3F8A7989AAB68E267891CB819AB9024D04DB430D6B8D8E692D64652CA2645681
Host:localhost:3080
Origin:http://localhost:3080
Referer:http://localhost:3080/admin/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
des:HelpDesk
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarylgAXmkMLtLGhRRU4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="avator.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarylgAXmkMLtLGhRRU4--
```

and then with no error I just get redirected to my start page, I don't know how to track the event that changed state.

the interesting thing are when I heat breakpoint in dev console and I wait just for few minute, then there is no state change and everything goes well.

near to pull my hair.
any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show the complete code of `uploadIssueAttachment`? The problem could be because of something else. Btw in the success callback you are missing `}`. Also, is there a way we can reproduce / test this issue, jsfiddle/plunkr?

Comment: i edited the code , so it now contain complete function

Comment: As Yash has mentioned there doesn't seem to be any issue with this code. Is there any way we can reproduce this issue? Btw, how many files are you uploading at a time? Also try putting `alert` in catch block and check if you get to see any error message.

Answer (score 0):

You havent wrote which version you are using but I think this structure will help you .Its always good to use then...catch in angular success is now deprecated.
[You can see it here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promises%E2%80%93then-vs-success)

upload Structure(with then...catch)

```
$upload.upload({
    url: '<YOUR URL>'
    file: <file>
}).progress(function (evt) {
    // progress = parseFloat(evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
}).then(function(result) {
    //handle successful result
}).catch(function(errorCallback){
    //you can see error here
});
```

Let me know if it wont work.

**Edited**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       console.log(toState); //put break point over here try to debug
       console.log(fromState);
    });
```

Comment: I am using version 3.2.5. I changed my upload to your version, but the problem still exists.

Comment: yes . there is no error, so catch doesn't hit at all, success callback runs and then at the end, i get redirected

Comment: ok then your code seems perfect for upload can you provide some more code I mean what you are doing in success method?

Comment: and in this function `uploadIssueAttachment`

Comment: i edited the code , so it now contain complete function

Comment: There is no call which can change your state in there.
Do you applied watch on `newIssueAttachments` that may cause something.

Comment: I don't think I can help you by just seeing this code there may be some resolve url condition which leads to the front page of your app or something else. I have edited my answer that can help you to debug it.

Comment: no . when i set a breakpoint in }).progress(function (evt) {   and wait for 2-3 minute then , after success i dont get redirected .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149387/discussion-between-yash-ganatra-and-arash).